# Issue with displaying uploaded images in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, image, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4

I have had an issue with displaying uploaded images in my `laravel` application. The problem is, i had a directory in my public folder named *uploads* and this is where i stored uploaded images.

This displays images fine on my `localhost` but on my *liveserver*, the images don't display but when i saved the images this way *public/images/uploads* i.g. moving the *uploads* folder into the images folder the images display on the *liveserver*.

I have saved the image link in my `database` like so *uploads/imagename.ext* and i display it in the browser like so

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/{{($pgIndex->introTextImgLink)}}" style="width:100%; height:250px;"/>
```

The *uploads* folder has file `permission 707`. I really like to keep storing my uploaded images in the *public/uploads* folder but i am not sure what i could be doing wrong on my live server.

Comment: Are the images uploaded? I mean do you have problem uploading images to your production server or the problem is with displaying them?

Comment: I do not have any problem with uploading.Only displaying

Comment: I have fixed this issue. The problem was in my htaccess.